# eclipse maven Circular placeholder reference Error using profiles

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-profiles

When I packaged target/war using maven with profiles, eclipse refreshed project, and try to launch it on tomcat, I get constantly

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
[applicationContext-resources.xml]: Circular placeholder reference
'jdbc.driverClassName' in property definitions
```

Mention: I use STS 3.7.1, which is based on eclipse 4.5.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the project -> Maven -> Select Maven Profiles... and pickup your profile.

...This is stupid behavior in eclipse

Comment: this is indeed quite confusing. This was the solution to my problem. I would like to add, if you have a multi-part solution, you should pick a profile in all of them. Thank you